# How to make snap scroll effect like fullpage.js with pure javascript without jQuery

Tags: javascript, scroll, fullpage.js

looking for solution how to make this snap scrol http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage but without huge script. how to make it more simple. 
will be really happy to hear your experience.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying the [pure Javascript fullPage.js version](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/pure%20javascript%20(Alpha))? :) 
17Kb, although it provides less features.

By the way, fullpage.js is not a "huge script" as you said. It is only 30Kb and 7Kb gzipped. I would say it is quite a light script in size for all the features it provides.

You can argue you don't want to import the 80Kb of jQuery + 30 of fullpage.js, fair enough, but I wouldn't call fullPage.js a "huge script" :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
Probably will go for it:)